# How can we copy 20+ azure sql tables to blob storage in delta format

Tags: azure-data-factory

I used a lookup activity to get the tablenames and then I used a Foreach activity and inside the foreach activities i created a dataflow which will have source as an azure sql dataset and table name will be parameterised and source dataset i created is inline and file type would be json. and in the dataflow parameters i used the parameter for tablename i.e @item.TABLE_NAME

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#blob-storage-as-a-sink-type), Azure Data Factory supports the following file formats. Delta table format is not supported by ADF.

•   Avro format

•   Binary format

•   Delimited text format

•   JSON format

•   ORC format

•   Parquet format

Comment: Delta format is supported in Copy as a dataset type (Delta Lake) and in Mapping Data Flows as an inline type (Delta Lake). It would be good if you could open a PR or issue against this doc so we can clarify in the documentation. Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. Are you running into challenges?